# Does the `-r` flag with `read` cause or NOT cause character escape?

Tags: linux

I am very confused about the `read -r` flag, or the meaning of "escape" in this contexts. [The manual](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html) says regarding this flag:

```
-r  =  do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
```

But this seems to me to be the OPPOSITE of what the flag does. For example, running:

```
read -d '' VAR <<EOF                                                                               
This is the \t first line
This is the second line
EOF
echo $VAR
```

... gives:

```
This is the t first line
This is the second line
```

But that seems to me as though the 't' character has NOT been escaped by the backslash. Conversely, when I add the -r flag, I get the following:

```
This is the     first line
This is the second line
```

... where it appears to me as though the 't' character HAS been escaped due to the `-r` flag. So am I misunderstanding the meaning of the word "escape", or misunderstanding something else going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you're doing `read -r -d '' VAR`? When running this command for me, it outputs `\t` correctly. My only guess is your echo command is expanding the `\t` part. Try doing `printf '%s\n' "${VAR}"` and see if it outputs correctly

Comment: How do you "get the following"?  When the backslash is read as an escape character, `\t` is translated exactly as the string `t`.  If you use `read -r`, the string will instead get the literal text `\t`.  But if you print that string certain ways, that `\t` will be translated to a tab character.  How are you printing the string?

Comment: I was using echo both times. When I use `printf '%s\n' "${VAR}"`, it gives '... the t first ...' without the -r flag, and gives '... the \t first ...' with the -r flag. I'm still fairly confused though.

Comment: Like I said it sounds like your echo is expanding the `\t` which isn't default behavior, but you can test it with `foo='foo\tbar'; echo -e "${foo}"; echo -E "${foo}"`. It should expand the tab on the first, and not on the second.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect your confusion is caused by the manner in which you are determining the final content of the string.  When backslashes are treated as an escape sequence (eg, when you do not use `-r`), `\t` is treated the same as a `t`.  When they are not, it is treated as the literal two characters `\t`.  Consider:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh

read a << 'EOF'
a: Without -r: foo\tbar
EOF

read -r b << 'EOF'
b: With -r   : foo\tbar
EOF

printf "a = %s\n" "$a"
printf "b = %s\n" "$b"

printf "printf interprets the string: $a\n"
printf "printf interprets the string: $b\n"
$ ./a.sh
a = a: Without -r: footbar
b = b: With -r   : foo\tbar
printf interprets the string: a: Without -r: footbar
printf interprets the string: b: With -r   : foo        bar
```

Comment: Thanks. Follow up question: when I add \$PWD to my heredoc, I'd now expect -r to cause $PWD to be expanded because \ does NOT escape the $ symbol; but shell expansion does not take place. How come?

Comment: Don't put `EOF` in quotes if you want expansion, see https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents

Comment: @Magnus, the options to `read` have no bearing on the interpolation of the heredoc.  If you want variables expanded, omit the quotes on the delimiter.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks. What I think had me so confused about the term "escape" is that -r is apparently making "\t" preserve the literal character of "t" (escape => preservation), whereas I'm used to thinking of the backslash in "\t" as transforming the normal meaning of "t" (escape => transformation). So when it says that -r does NOT allow backslashes to escape, I expected a LACK of transformation when reading the output VAR. But now that I understand that -r controls the interpretation of the input string, not the interpretation of the string saved to VAR, the situation is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their input. OK, this is one of those pesky things in bash that is clearer to me now, but had me confused initially. Here's my summary understanding.

There are, in a sense, three strings at play here:

- The string of characters input to the heredoc,
- The string of characters output from the heredoc and input to read,
- The string of characters output from read and input to VAR

The string of characters being fed into the heredoc is, of course, whatever you type between the delimiters. But the string of characters output by the heredoc will depend on its own rules (viz. on whether the delimiter is quoted or not).

Next, the string of characters output by the heredoc will go into read, but the string of characters to be output by read (and saved into VAR) will depend on the presence/absence of the `-r` flag. If the string of characters input to read contain backslashes, then `read` without `-r` will first escape any such backlash-prefixed sequence -- thus modifying the string of characters -- and saving it into VAR.

But `read -r` will not attempt to interpret the backslashes, leaving the input text "as is" when outputting to VAR. Hence, the original `\t` is preserved with `read -r` and thus interpreted as a tab in the final `echo $VAR`.

My confusion primarily lay in my lack of discernment of the three separate strings of characters at play here (not echo vs printf).

Answer (score 0):

The escaping that a backslash does as input to `read`, is to prevent the next character from being treated as a separator:

```
$ read -r a b <<< 'foo\ bar'; printf "<%s> <%s>\n" "$a" "$b"
<foo\> <bar>
$ read    a b <<< 'foo\ bar'; printf "<%s> <%s>\n" "$a" "$b"
<foo bar> <>
```

Without it, backslashes are removed as part of the escape processing. With it, they are kept as-is.

Having the `\t` turn into a hard tab is due to `echo`, some implementations of it do that by default, some don't.